# BarRenderer is a raw type. References to generic type BarRenderer<T> should be parameterized?

Tags: androidplot

Eclipse shows me the following warning:

"BarRenderer is a raw type. References to generic type BarRenderer should be parameterized"

from the line:

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer)plot.getRenderer(BarRenderer.class);
```

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: First thing's first: Do you know what a generic type is? (E.g. `BarRenderer<SomeClass>`.) If not, you should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do here (have you created a custom renderer etc.) but to get past your immediate error you can try changing the line above to this:

```
BarRenderer<BarFormatter> renderer = (BarRenderer<BarFormatter>)plot.getRenderer(BarRenderer.class);
```